# No me carga los departamentos escogiendo el País

Tags: c#

Este código lo tengo para llamar `combobox` `país` y d el escoger un departamento pero no me los carga por id si no me los envia todos.

```
private void cboPais_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cboPais.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = CargarTabla("Pais","Nombre='"+cboPais.Text+"'");
   CargarComboBox(cboDepartamento, "Departamento", "IdPais = " + dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0], 1);


            }
        }

        private void cboDepartamento_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (cboDepartamento.SelectedIndex != 0) {
                CargarComboBox(cboMunicipio, "Municipio", "IdDepartamento="+DevolverCampo("Departamento","Nombre='"+cboDepartamento.Text+"'",0),2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** ¿Cuál es el código de los métodos: `CargarTabla() y CargarComboBox()`?. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Answer (score 6):

Hay algunos puntos que veo incorrectos

Primero dices que se debe cargar por id, pero veo que haces uso del `cboPais.Text` con lo cual no estas recuperando el id sino el texto.

Si asignaste el `DataSource` del combobox de paises, seguramente defines el `ValueMember` y el `DisplayMember`, por lo tanto para tomar el id usarias la propiedad `SelectedValue`

Por otro lado tu codigo no deberia estas haciendo uso de un metodo `CargarTabla()` de esa forma ya que no veo permitas el uso de parametros, tu codigo deberia ser

```
public DataTable ObtenerDepartamentos(int idPais)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))   
    {   
        string query = "select * from Departamentos WHERE idPais = @id";   

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idPais);   

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);     
        da.Fill(dt);   
    } 

    return dt;
}
```

no crees funcionalidad generica que aplique malas practicas en el codigo, es mejor si defines una capa de datos que retorne funcionalidad reutilizable

Esa funcionalidad la usarias

```
private void cboPais_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int idPais = Convert.Toint32(cboPais.SelectedValue);
    DataTable dt = ObtenerDepartamentos(idPais);

    cboDepartamento.ValueMember = "id";
    cboDepartamento.DisplayMember = "descripcion";
    cboDepartamento.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: *no crees funcionalidad generica que aplique malas practicas en el codigo, es mejor si defines una capa de datos que retorne funcionalidad reutilizable*: Esto no se enfatiza lo suficiente. Gracias por destacarlo.